# OkHttp post content is empty in release build after migrate to androidX

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp, androidx

Before migrating to androidX, the release build is working fine with every HTTP request.

After migrating to androidX, every **GET** request is working, but all of the **POST** request is not working. It can't send arguments to the server-side. All the content of the **POST** request is empty.

The only change I've done is migrate this project to androidX.

I'm not sure where I can look for more insight... :(

[update]: add interface and POJO by recommending from [kushan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3582305/kushan) comments :)

interface

```
@POST("/api/preference")
Call<RoasterPreference> updatePreference(@Body RoasterPreference roasterPreference);
```

POJO object

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RoasterPreference {

  @SerializedName("type")
  private String type;

  @SerializedName("value")
  private String value;

  public RoasterPreference(String _type,String _value){

    type = _type;
    value = _value;
  }
}
```

OkHttp log from debugging build:

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.0.1:9999/api/preference
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 29
{"type":"t_unit","value":"0"}
--> END POST (29-byte body)
```

OkHttp log from release build:

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.0.1:9999/api/preference
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 2
{}
--> END POST (2-byte body)
```

the debugger in debug mode

[image]

the debugger in release mode

[image]

diff in build.gradle when migrating to androidX

[image]

dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.HotBitmapGG:RingProgressBar:V1.2.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
// Required -- JUnit 4 framework
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
// Optional -- Robolectric environment
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
// Optional -- Mockito framework
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0'

// google services
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: post the interface where the method is declared

Comment: also post the POJO object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when upgrading to Android Studio 3.4 later, R8 is defaulted on.
So Gson library needs to add a new proguard rule.

```
# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```

ref:https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Comment: Yes! I forgot the other thing I do is upgrade my Android Studio to 3.5 since many fellows saying it's so good to use! Thank you for this answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `@SerializedName("YOUR_NAME")` and `@Expose` to each attributes in your RoasterPreference.